# I have a problem with oracle sql developer include of a with function not working

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a file containing a WITH FUNCTION. Because of security limitations, I can not place the function into the database, so I am using the excellent WITH FUNCTION syntax to get around that limitation.

I have tried to include the function (starting with the WITH) in a SQL DEVELOPER CALL Using:

```
@x:\fldr1\fldr2\WITH_FUNCTION.sql
SELECT WITH_FUNCTION(arg) FROM DUAL;
```

I get an error message that function is bad, even though if I copy the body of the function in the calling window it works fine.

I have tried removing the WITH in the included file and putting it into the calling window:

```
WITH
@x:\fldr1\fldr2\WITH_FUNCTION.sql
SELECT WITH_FUNCTION(arg) FROM DUAL;
```

Get a WITH syntax error message, What magic is required to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post contents of the .sql file, but - if it contains a function, you can't use it as you planned to.

I suggest you write the whole query, store it into the .sql file and run it in SQL Developer as

```
@with_function.sql
```

The result will be displayed in the "Script output" window.

---

Or, maybe simpler / even better, copy/paste contents of the .sql file into SQL Developer and run it there as if you wrote it *right now*.

Comment: Thank you. My objective was to not have to include the details of the function in each script that uses it. But I guess that is not allowed..